# Create jar in IntelliJ without including libraries?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, jar

I'm using intellij to create a jar, however I don't want the jar to include required libraries; I want the libraries to be loaded from a specific folder (as if I were running the .class file with a classpath).

In `Project Structure -> Artifacts -> Output Layout`, I tried removing the libraries and putting their locations in the `Class Path` text area,  however when I try running the program I get an error saying that my program's main isn't found/in the class path.

How can I make a jar that doesn't have the library jars packaged into it, in intellij?

Comment: Post the command line you're using and the complete error message, at minimum.

Comment: (a) If you do not include the required libraries, how do you expect it to run? - are you at least specifying them in the classpath at run-time? (b) when creating a new JAR file (without dependencies) you are be able to specify the 'main' class for your artifact - did you skip that step?

Comment: @ochi: (a) by using the standard technique, supported natively by java: specifying the classpath in the manifest of the jar file.

Comment: @JBNizet - I know that... just wondered if the OP is doing it (and if not, that might be why an error is given - although the error is currently pointing to a missing or incomplete manifest file)

Comment: @ochi The main class is specified for the artifact. It's weird, if I add the missing libraries it works. If I don't, I get that "Could not find or load main class" error. Which doesn't make sense, since the main class is not in any of the libraries.

Comment: In your manifest, do you also specify the path to the other dependencies (i.e. jar files)? the Main will not load if it cannot find the other dependencies (in other words, it cannot load partially)

Answer (score 1):

Okay, I found what the problem was. Thanks to @ochi, I learned that Main will not be load if other dependencies cannot be found. The problem was with the classpath in my manifest.mf

Originally, I had my class path like this:

```
C:\something\something.jar;C:\else\else.jar;
```

(I assumed it was like how you do the classpath using -cp, when executing from command line).

The correct format was like this:

```
\C:\something\something.jar \C:\else\else.jar;
```

Comment: yes, I was suspecting something along the lines... nice find